# how do I solve deadlock of proxy example trafficlock and ssl handshakelock?

Tags: java, netty

I combined large parts of the netty examples HexdumpProxy (http://netty.io/docs/stable/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/proxy/)  and SecureChat (http://netty.io/docs/stable/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/securechat) to form an SSL (and non-SSL) capable proxy (to a non-SSL back end). This seemed like a good idea, proved to be simple enough and it is exactly what I need, currently.

The proxy example code uses a trafficlock lock as a solution to a race condition reported in 2010 (http://markmail.org/message/x7jc6mqx6ripynqf) happening around saturated channels and setting the writeable and readable state of the incoming and outgoing channels.

Now, in my combined example, under higher load, this leads to a deadlock because another lock "handshakelock" in the SSL code is intertwined. See the profiler diagnostic output below.

I fear that, even after reading the original discussion, I do not understand the underlying issue with the traffic lock good enough to find a straightforward solution for this deadlock.

(this was with netty 3.2.6)

```
Java-level deadlock has been detected

This means that some threads are blocked waiting to enter a synchronization block or
waiting to reenter a synchronization block after an Object.wait() call, where each thread
owns one monitor while trying to obtain another monitor already held by another thread.

Deadlock:


New I/O client worker #1-2 is waiting to lock java.lang.Object@7900f3c9 which is held by New I/O server worker #1-2
New I/O server worker #1-2 is waiting to lock java.lang.Object@2d854f2f which is held by New I/O client worker #1-2




Thread stacks


New I/O client worker #1-2 [BLOCKED; waiting to lock java.lang.Object@7900f3c9]
org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrap(SslHandler.java:665) <== sync handshakelock
org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.handleDownstream(SslHandler.java:461)
org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:591)
org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:776)
org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:632)
org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.handleDownstream(OneToOneEncoder.java:70)
org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:591)
org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:582)
org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:611)
org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:578)
org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.write(AbstractChannel.java:251)
com.activevideo.frontend.ProxyInboundHandler$OutboundHandler.messageReceived(ProxyInboundHandler.java:162) <== sync trafficlock
org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:80)
org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:783)
org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:302)
org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:317)
org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:299)
org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:216)
org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:80)
org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:274)
org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:261)
org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:351)
org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.processSelectedKeys(NioWorker.java:282)
org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:202)
org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:44)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(unknown source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(unknown source)
java.lang.Thread.run(unknown source)


New I/O server worker #1-2 [BLOCKED; waiting to lock java.lang.Object@2d854f2f]
com.activevideo.frontend.ProxyInboundHandler.channelInterestChanged(ProxyInboundHandler.java:138) <== sync trafficlock
org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:116)
org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:783)
org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.channelInterestChanged(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:192)
org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:116)
org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:783)
org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.channelInterestChanged(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:192)
org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:116)
org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:783)
org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.channelInterestChanged(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:192)
org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:116)
org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireChannelInterestChanged(Channels.java:335)
org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.setInterestOps(NioWorker.java:728)
org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.handleAcceptedSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:129)
org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:76)
org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:771)
org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.handleDownstream(SslHandler.java:430)
org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:591)
org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:776)
org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.handleDownstream(OneToOneEncoder.java:60)
org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:591)
org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:582)
org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.setInterestOps(Channels.java:652)
org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.setInterestOps(AbstractChannel.java:222)
org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.setReadable(AbstractChannel.java:244)
com.activevideo.frontend.SSLProxyInboundHandler$BackendConnector$1.operationComplete(SSLProxyInboundHandler.java:92)
org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListener(DefaultChannelFuture.java:381)
org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.addListener(DefaultChannelFuture.java:148)
com.activevideo.frontend.SSLProxyInboundHandler$BackendConnector.operationComplete(SSLProxyInboundHandler.java:87)
org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListener(DefaultChannelFuture.java:381)
org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListeners(DefaultChannelFuture.java:367)
org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.setSuccess(DefaultChannelFuture.java:316)
org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.setHandshakeSuccess(SslHandler.java:1040)
org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrapNonAppData(SslHandler.java:838)
org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:907)    <=== sync handshakelock
org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:620)
org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:282)
org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:214)
org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:80)
org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:274)
org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:261)
org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:351)
org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.processSelectedKeys(NioWorker.java:282)
org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:202)
org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:44)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(unknown source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(unknown source)
java.lang.Thread.run(unknown source)
```

Comment: BTW 3.2.6 is quite old .. you should upgrade to 3.4.0.Final

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I fixed it.

The solution to the earlier race condition in the Proxy example unnecessarily includes the call to write() in the synchronized block.

The original problem there was this (rare) race condition between the outgoing thread (TO) and incoming thread (TI):

1. TO: inboundChannel.write() (at messageReceived)
2. TO: inboundChannel.isWritable() returns false (at messageReceived)
3. Then pending writes issued at (1) are flushed
4. TI: inboundChannel.isWritable() returns true (at channelInterestChanged)
5. TI: outboundChannel.setReadable(true) (at channelInterestChanged)
6. TO: outboundChannel.setReadable(false) (at messageReceived)

The solution in 2010 was to introduce synchronizing (using 'trafficlock') around setting the readable flag in the messageReceived() handler of both the inboundChannel and outboundChannel (and also in the InterestChanged handler), like so:

```
synchronized (trafficLock) {
  outboundChannel.write(msg);
  // If outboundChannel is saturated, do not read until notified in
  // OutboundHandler.channelInterestChanged().
  if (!outboundChannel.isWritable()) {
    e.getChannel().setReadable(false);
  }
}
```

This indeed solves the race condition, as you prevent steps 3, 4 and 5 to interfere with the steps 2 and 6. However, it is safe to leave step 1, the write(), out of the synchronized block.

The call to write() caused the deadlock, because way down that call in the SSLHandler, it uses another lock handshakelock.

So.. I moved the call to write() outside the synchronized block in both locations. The deadlock is now gone. I suggest the 'official' proxy example is changed accordingly.